# Using Default Properties in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS app. In this app, I'm working on a custom directive. This directive will render differently based on a custom attribute value. Currently, My directive looks like this:

```
<my-view size="small"></my-view>
...
<my-view></my-view>
...
<my-view size="large"></my-view>
```

The code that defines this directive looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('myView', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      size: '=?'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      if (angular.isUndefined($scope.size)) {
        $scope.size = 'medium';
      }
    },
    template: '<div>{{size}}<br /><div ng-if="size == 'large'">I'm HUGE</div><div ng-if="size=='small'">I'm a wee little thing</div><div ng-if="size == medium">I'm the default</div></div>'
  };
});
```

For some reason, my directive isn't working. I noticed the first {{size}} doesn't print out anything. Yet, if I do a console.log($scope.size) in the controller, I get the size displayed in the console window. Its like the view is rendering before the controller is done initializing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use two-way model binding (scope:{=}). You should use attribute string binding (scope:{@})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were 2 things wrong with your directive:

1. You should escape the apostrophes of your template.
2. If you are going to pass an attribute as a string you should use `@`, the equal sign `=` is for data binding a property of the directive with a property of the parent scope.

So your directvive should look like this:

```
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.test = 'asdf';
  }])
  .directive('myView', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict:'E',    
    scope: {
      size: '@'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      if (angular.isUndefined($scope.size)) {
        $scope.size = 'medium';
      }
    },
    template: '<div>{{size}}<br/><div ng-if="size ==\'large\'">I\'m HUGE</div><div ng-if="size==\'small\'">I\'m a wee little thing</div><div ng-if="size == medium">I\'m the default</div></div>'
  };
});
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/c5mtmqkd/1/)